# Начать писать код для Android

Tags: java, android

я новичок в программировании. Не так давно начал изучать C# и Java.
Для С# выбрал среду visual studio 2012, а для Java NetBeans.
Собственно появилось пару идей для приложений на платформе android. Прошу посоветовать хорошую, а главное удобную среду для таких целей, что бы в ней был компилятор Java и эмулятор Android. Грубо говоря я хочу просто писать код и на практике проверять уже в эмуляторе.

Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы.

P.S. Знаю что для visual studio 2017 можно каким-то образом подключить эмулятор android, но я так и не разобрался как это сделать.

Comment: Попробуйте IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Используйте Android Studio, в  IntelliJ IDEA нет особого смысла, если собираетесь писать только под Android.

Comment: Android Studio - больше вариантов нет

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio - официальная среда разработки под систему Android от Google. Сейчас уже доведена до ума, что даже что-то другое использовать нет смысла. Здесь есть и менеджер SDK и AVD и много других инструментов. Можно писать на языках Java и Kotlin.